# select distinct value in sql with 35 columns

Tags: sql

I have table that contains 35 columns, how would I select only the distinct records from that table, this is what my query looks like:

```
`SELECT field1, field2, field3 etc... from table1 group by field1, field2, field3 etc...`
```

This gets me the unique results that I want but I have 35 columns, its too long to group all 35 rows - is there any efficient way of doing this:

by doing this, I get repeated results:

`SELECT distinct * from table1`

Comment: Can you please set up a SQLFiddle and add some sample data? I cannot reproduce this error on SQL Server at least. Test link: http://rextester.com/RPYO92828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISTINCT will be also faster:

Your query should looks like:

```
SELECT distinct field1, field2, field3 etc... 
from table1
```

Use distinct once.
This will affect all columns.

Comment: if i am using this query in my c# or java code then it will be too long. Is there any other way?

Comment: Do You have idexes, set on table?

Comment: Grouping/using distinct with many columns (or) on table with many rows will increase performance time. Maybe You HAVE TO set indexes on grouped columns first.

Comment: Indexes are very important part of DB design http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `GROUP BY` if you use `DISTINCT`. But you have to list all the fields that you want to show, and for sure not the primary key.

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 etc... 
FROM   table1
```